# How do I use ES6 template literal syntax with back-ticks to display each entry of the "result" object's failure array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Each entry is supposed to be wrapped inside an li element with the class attribute text-warning, and listed within the resultDisplayArray.

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  "use strict";


  const resultDisplayArray = `${result.failure[0]}`;


  return resultDisplayArray;
}
/**
 * makeList(result.failure) should return:
 * [ `<li class="text-warning">no-var</li>`,
 *   `<li class="text-warning">var-on-top</li>`, 
 *   `<li class="text-warning">linebreak</li>` ]
 **/
const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array.map. `map`returns a new array

```js
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};

function makeList(arr) {
  "use strict";
  return arr.map(item => `<li class='text-warning'>${item}</li>`)
}

console.log(makeList(result.failure))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like following

```js
const result = {success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]};

function makeList(arr) {
  return arr.map(v => `<li class='text-warning'>${v}</li>`);
}
const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
console.log(resultDisplayArray);
```